# "Country of Residence" for a Nonimmigrant residing in the US

Tags: usa, residency

I am filing FBI form [I-783](https://forms.fbi.gov/identity-history-summary-checks-review/q384893984839334.pdf) to request a criminal record check. The form asks for my "Country of Residence". I have been living and working in the US for over a year on a work visa (E-1).

What is my country of residence? Is it the US or my home country? USCIS does not consider me a resident, but the IRS and my state do.

Comment: IUSCIS doesn't much concern itself with the question of residence.  The fact that you are a nonimmigrant doesn't stop you from being a resident.  Some people reside in the US for years orI even decades in one nonimmigrant status or another.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. What got me confused is that USCIS also has a "Permanent Resident" status.

Comment: That is true, of course.  Once someone with an immigrant visa enters the US, that person becomes a "lawful permanent resident," commonly known as a green card holder.  It's also possible for a nonimmigrant to adjust status to that of a lawful permanent resident.  But I don't think they ever use "resident" outside the phrase "permanent resident."  Given that you've lived in the US for over a year I think you ought to say you're a US resident.  That's what I would do, anyway, but I'm not confident enough in that advice to post it as an answer.